# How can SFTP/Jetbrains be configured to allow remote access to two directories

Tags: ssh, apache2, sftp

SFTP is the product's (*jetbrains*) method for remote file modification. The targeted users have a **home** directory and they need access to **/var/www/html**. Unfortunately SFTP requires a *single chrooted directory* per logical user.
Is there a way to create a new logical sftp account to permit upload/download to /var/www/html that also allows httpd/ Apache to operate normally on these same directories?

### Alternatively is there any option to use ssh/scp as the delivery method or other methods?

as requested this is an issue on both rhel 7.3 and ubuntu 20.04

the issue is how to configure SFTP to allow edits in 2 separate trees where the upper layers of the tree are not all root and where the permissions have different requirements from a chrooted filesystem

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1357223/edit) and add the details.

Comment: possible methods under investigation using link(https://devanswers.co/configure-sftp-web-server-document-root/) and link(https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561353/how-to-setup-user-access-control-for-apache-ssh-sftp)  in case this question comes up again